# Swapping 3 items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 HTML list items on a navbar. I want the `onclick` response to be that whichever element is clicked the text swaps with the middle element. The clicked item moves to the middle and the item that was in the middle moves to the position of the item that replaced it. I Have been trying and researching with both Javascript and jQuery. There are many answers to this with only 2 elements. Nothing I can find for moving 3 around.

This is the HTML:

```
<li>
    <a id="i1" onclick='swap();' href="#">being</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="active" href="#">doing</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="i2" onclick='swap();' href="#">done</a>
</li>
```

This is the JavaScript I have so far, but it just cycles through them:

```
function swap() {
    var i1 = document.getElementById("i1");
    var active = document.getElementById("active");
    var i2 = document.getElementById("i2");
    var initiali1 = i1.innerHTML;
    var initialactive = active.innerHTML;
    var initiali2 = i2.innerHTML;

    i1.innerHTML=active.innerHTML;
    active.innerHTML=initiali1;
    i2.innerHTML=active.innerHTML;
    active.innerHTML=initiali2;
}
```

Comment: then add the sample code that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you are looking for, try following code:

```
$('li').click(function(){


if( $(this).index() == 0)
    $(this).insertBefore( $(this).parent().find("li").eq(2));
else
    $(this).insertBefore( $(this).parent().find("li").eq(1));

});
```

Comment: Amazing. It works perfectly. I still don't yet understand how. But thank you so much.

Comment: if index is 0 it swaps it with 2 else if it is 2 it swaps it with 0, middle one remains as it is, please accept it as answer